# ESP8266 + MOSFETs + LED strips

Tags: mosfet, led, circuit-design, esp8266

I'm trying to drive with PWM the usual 12V LED strip with a *WeMos D1 Mini* and a bunch of MOSFETs.

Here's the circuit:

[image]

What do you think of it regarding MOSFET choice and resistor placement?

---

*Edit* (from the comments)

The LED strips have a length of around 2 to 3 meters.
The LEDs are 5050 clones.

Comment: What's the strip's length? And what's its cable length? Do you know if the strip's LEDs have current limiter resistors (quite possibly they do but it's still worth to check)?

Comment: 1k on the gate might be a little high, since the fets have almost 1uf of input capacitance, 330r might be better (faster turn on) and still only present 10ma peak to the GPIO. The rest is fine up to 2-3 amps w/o cooling.

Comment: Around 2/3m of length. LEDs are 5050 clones.

Comment: @dandavis The Ciss (input capacitance) of the MOSFET is less than 1 nF. 1 k gate resistance is fine, unless the OP is going to drive the MOSFETs with hundreds of kHz.

Answer (score 0):

your connections are correct.

---

Resistors R4, R5, R6:

You may safely remove them. They are not needed.
ESP32 after booting, in fact, will take software control of the 3 GPIO output lines.

---

Resistors R1, R2, R3:

You may safely remove them. They are not needed.
If you don't remove them you will slow down the rising and falling edges of the PWM control voltages and the MOSFET's will waste power and possibly get hot.
If you want to keep them I would use 10 to 100 Ohm.

---

MOSFETs Q1, Q2, Q3:

Good choice. The maximum threshold voltage is 1,1 Volt which is lower than GPIO output voltage 3,3 V or 5 V. See the picture below.

[image]

Comment: R4/5/6: I added them to have a reliable behaviour _during_ boot (btw I'm using an esp8266). R1/2/3: ok, I will reduce the value. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I understand what you write.

At boot though GPIO pins are not left floating by the ESP32. They have a well defined state that in 99% of the CPU in the world is:

Input + weak pull-up

Yet the boot sequence lasts a few milliseconds.

In a production environment your boss will ask you to remove those resistors.